# Application could not be started

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am unable to get my application to run an Android device from Visual Studio 2015/Xamarin. It fails to start on the device, giving this message:

```
The application could not be started.
Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).  
Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.
```

So I added the decorator `[Activity(MainLauncher = true)]` to the MainActivity.

I checked that in `Build-> Configuration Manager`, AnyCPU, Build, and Deploy are checked.

Restarted, same result, did not start on device and gives same messages.

A [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294649/xamarin-android-visual-studio-the-application-could-not-be-started) suggests that the previous app may not have been entirely removed, so issuing this command from the adb shell:

```
adb -s 09103e9 shell pm list packages
```

shows the packages on the device:

```
package:com.google.android.ears
package:com.android.launcher
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.rovio.popcorn
package:com.nuance.xt9.input
package:com.google.android.exchange
package:com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.google.android.nfcprovision
package:com.android.phone
package:com.android.calculator2
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.google.android.gsf.login
package:com.android.bluetooth
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.google.android.email
package:Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23
package:com.android.providers.downloads.ui
package:com.mobilerise.mystreetview
package:com.android.documentsui
package:com.android.sharedstoragebackup
package:com.android.vpndialogs
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.marvin.talkback
package:jp.co.omronsoft.iwnnime.ml.kbd.white
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.google.android.deskclock
package:com.google.android.gms
package:com.google.android.apps.currents
package:com.google.android.setupwizard
package:com.example.android.osmdroidofflinedemo
package:com.android.settings
package:com.meraki.sm
package:com.google.android.street
package:com.hp.android.printservice
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.google.android.music
package:com.android.musicvis
package:eu.thedarken.sdm
package:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
package:com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
package:net.osmand
package:com.android.packageinstaller
package:com.google.android.backuptransport
package:com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app
package:com.google.android.tts
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.android.noisefield
package:com.google.android.apps.maps
package:com.google.android.apps.cloudprint
package:com.funtrigger.appinstaller
package:com.wf.wellsfargomobile
package:com.pandora.android
package:com.android.wallpapercropper
package:com.android.location.fused
package:com.android.backupconfirm
package:com.android.providers.settings
package:jp.co.omronsoft.iwnnime.ml
package:si.formias.keepscreenon
package:com.google.android.apps.docs
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.amazon.mp3
package:com.android.browser.provider
package:com.android.musicfx
package:com.google.android.apps.books
package:com.android.phasebeam
package:com.google.android.videos
package:com.google.android.inputmethod.pinyin
package:com.google.android.gallery3d
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin
package:com.esri.arcgis.collector
package:com.google.android.partnersetup
package:com.wunderground.android.weather
package:com.adobe.reader
package:com.android.proxyhandler
package:com.android.inputdevices
package:com.andrewshu.android.reddit
package:com.android.wallpaper.holospiral
package:com.google.android.feedback
package:com.google.android.talk
package:com.android.nfc
package:com.google.android.apps.enterprise.dmagent
package:com.android.providers.userdictionary
package:com.google.android.inputmethod.korean
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.android.pacprocessor
package:com.quickoffice.android
package:com.google.android.keep
package:com.android.printspooler
package:android
package:com.android.providers.contacts
package:com.techsmith.apps.fuse
package:com.android.externalstorage
package:com.mictale.gpsessentials
package:com.estrongs.android.taskmanager
package:com.android.dreams.basic
package:com.google.android.apps.plus
package:com.android.vending
package:com.google.android.play.games
package:com.android.systemui
package:com.android.keychain
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.google.android.tag
package:com.android.wallpaper
package:com.google.android.GoogleCamera
package:com.estrongs.android.pop
package:com.google.android.apps.magazines
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:Mono.Android.DebugRuntime
package:com.google.earth
package:com.google.android.gsf
package:com.android.keyguard
package:com.google.android.calendar
package:com.android.facelock
package:com.android.chrome
package:com.android.shell
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
```

None of these are the application. Some suggestions on the web are to remove the
Mono packages, so I removed these with this command:

```
adb -s 091930e9 shell pm uninstall -k Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel-23
adb -s 091930e9 shell pm uninstall -k Mono.Android.DebugRuntime
```

but this had no effect. This are reinstalled upon starting the app from Visual Studio.

In VS `MyProject.Native.Droid properties > Android Options > Packaging`, unchecked Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)
No effect.

In VS `MyProject.Native.Droid properties > Android Options > Advanced`, verified that x68 was checked.

Looking at the build output as suggested by @hvaughn there is the following warning which is also a warning in the Error List:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. 
In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding> 
    MyProject.Native.Droid          
    One or more dependent assemblies have version conflicts
```

In the Error List it also says:

```
Do you want to fix these conflicts by adding binding redirrect records in the application configuration file?
```

I click Yes. This warning then goes away until the next build and reappears again, so this has no effect.

Then there is this:

```
:Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyD.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Deployment failed because of an internal error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
InternalError
Build succeeded.
Deploy successfully on Google Nexus 7
```

This happens on 2 devices, the Google Nexus 7 and a Samsung SM-T530NU.

The code is from a remote Git Repository.

On the suggestion of @Matt, I created a new Hello World type solution and it installs on the device.

Not sure what to do about this, the suggestions on the web for this error are removing the app, which I did using the `adb` as shown above. I'm also puzzled by the "Deploy successfully ..." message because it is not on the device.

EDIT

The solution was to do a factory reset. This tells me, that despite the various steps I took to delete the app/package, it was somehow still there.

Comment: See what the Build output says, this often has more helpful info. For me the problem was that I needed to check the x86 architecture in Android project properties but that was only because I was trying to run the app on the Xamarin Android emulator.

Comment: Added more info based on your suggestion

Comment: Do you have Android SDK 23 installed on your development machine?

Comment: Yes, but good thought.

Comment: Only other idea that occurs is to remove the `-3` switch from the `list packages` command, to make extra certain that a service component associated with the app is not still installed.

Comment: I've edited the question to show all packages. I don't see anything suspicous. Do you?

Comment: Can you install a new blank application with similar settings?

Comment: @Matt: On your suggestion, I created a blank app and that does install.

Comment: Did you use the same package name?

Comment: No, I created a new solution and project using all the defaults. So I created one with the same name as the other one and it installs as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find your package name by clicking your android project and then open properties, then select android manifest. 
Find the old app with the same package name remove it and everything should work.

It should look like this:[image: packagename]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying exactly what the package name is. Nonetheless, it is not listed when I do the aforementioned adb list packages command.

Comment: And you also can't find it in the installation list of apps with a broken icon? If at all possible reset the phone to factory defaults

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "broken icon". What I have done is issue the adb list packages command and I don't see the package name of the app the output.

Comment: Yeah some old default icon of Xamarin android. Please check if it is in the list of apps en not the adb list but in de settings of the phone. And give the phone a reboot.

Comment: Oh,ok, no it's not in Settings > Apps.

Comment: And a reboot or factory reset also does not fix this?

Comment: Haven't tried the reset yet. Last resort. Something that confuses me: When I run the app from VS/Xamarin, I get that error message (and the app doesn't run) but I see the app in Settings > App and I DO NOT see it in the "regular" Apps section.

Comment: Tried deleting the package, the restarting. No effect.

Comment: Then I only know of a factory reset to try to fix it

Comment: I finally did a factory reset, which fixed the problem.

Comment: Which, I should add, is not much of a solution.

Answer (score 7):

INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE means your app is already deployed on the device with an old version of Xamarin.

The deployment process removed your old app's icon but not the old app. So you now need to remove your app without having its icon before deploying again. This is a very old limitation of Xamarin deployment on Android. To do that:

- Go to settings / applications
- Find you app, it's name will be someting like com.company, not the app's name
- Delete it
- Redeploy

Comment: This list of apps is in the question and I see nothing related to the app.

Comment: That's not a package name. The package Name is like a domain name. It should start with com.companyname.appname

Comment: please add this line or edit

**Settings -> Apps -> All -> Then select your application**

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate the apk in release project configuration using an emulator and then install that apk file manually to the device and check if it shows the update screen or the new installation screen. If it shows the update screen then the application might be in your phone else there must be a problem in the solution. You can also try debugging the application using the Xamarin studio with the same sln file to check if there is a problem in VS2015.