# Avoiding Xamarin app "collision" when debugging

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

The root of the problem is perfectly explained here (mind you, my question is different from what can be found in this post): [Xamarin - Android - Visual Studio - The application could not be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294649/xamarin-android-visual-studio-the-application-could-not-be-started)

In my particular case:

1. Debug from PC1: everything OK
2. Debug from PC2 without uninstalling debug app from PC1: the error appears for the first time
3. Try everything to avoid this error. The app cannot be found in the phone, I deleted the files manually as one post suggested (this might have been a mistake). No "*myAppName*" files can be found in my phone.

So I have decided to **trick Android into thinking it is a different app**, and this is what my question is about.

I have changed everything I found in the project (namespace, blah blah) from "myAppName" to "slightlyDifferentAppName" but the problem persists... I have debugged different projects form PC2 and they work, which makes me think it is a "collision" between different signatures of the same app (because otherwise it makes no sense that it worked in PC1 and not in PC2).

My question is: what can I tweak in Visual Studio in order to trick Android into thinking it is a different app?

Comment: When I've hit this issue in the past, it's because PC1 and PC2 sign the app with different keystores. Even though Android is pretty free spirited regarding code signing, it still happens, and it will refuse to run an app that it thinks is signed with the wrong key. Uninstalling the app in the normal way (long press the icon and drag to uninstall) does not seem to delete Android's memory of that app's key. But when I've gone into the application manager and deleted that way, I was always successful.

Comment: @DylanS I think that's the same problem for me as well, but I can't seem to find a trace of the installed program (even in the application manager). I can't find any trace of it searching through all Android files either. Before debugging from PC2, it was there. But not anymore, apparently. That's why I was trying the "trick Android into thinking it's a different app" approach.

Comment: What about trying to install it from PC1 again (or just install the APK from PC1). Then delete it with the application manager. My guess is that Android stores app + code signing information somewhere in system files (no real clue). But if you reinstall the PC1 app, it should at least be available to uninstall with application manager.

Comment: @DylanS That is a very good idea! It makes sense, I'll try it. I'm currently at work so I won't be able to test it until I get home though.

Comment: If you only have PC2 available, it might work to just install from that and try the uninstall.

Comment: @DylanS I wasn't able to install it from PC2, it kept crashing at every debug/deployment and Android didn't show the application. However, the "go to PC1, re-install the app, and then un-install it" worked like a charm! Today PC2 has been able to deploy the application without any problem, at first try. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Happy to have helped!