# Xamarin Forms - PCL project The app could not be started

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and have a PCL based project created. All this application does is show a splash screen and then navigate to the next page. I am unable to get this to work on Android. Here is the link for the [splash screen](http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=294)

The error I get:

> The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has
>   been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity
>   (MainLauncher = true).
>
> Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this
>   project is set to Deploy for this configuration.

I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294649/xamarin-android-visual-studio-the-application-could-not-be-started) and tried all the solutions there and still have the same result

Any tips to fix this?

**Edit**

Android Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Splash.Splash" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon-3" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Splash.Splash" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:label="Splash screen" android:name="md5ac585b47313c1dc414c7b7a18f93e457.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon-3" android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" android:name="md5ac585b47313c1dc414c7b7a18f93e457.Splash">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="Splash.Splash.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.STM.STM" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Edit**

New Manifest below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Super.Super" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/stmicon-3"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Ensure the previous application is uninstalled. Use `adb uninstall <package name>` to manually remove this from your device.

Comment: I have done this too and still no effect

Comment: Can you post your final AndroidManifest.xml? It'll be in your obj/android folder.

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: Try removing the MainLauncher off one of the Activities. You have it on two.

Comment: tried it with MainLauncher=false and without MainLauncher present there too.. not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: It might be best to post a link to dropbox containing your project. I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: The problem arises when I change the android project's startup activity from `MainActivity: global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity` to `SplashScreen : Activity`

Comment: Name it `public class SplashActivity : Activity` and ensure it's not conflicting with other items named "Splash" like your Application name.

Comment: Remove all activity tags from the Manifest, it works without adding them manually.

Comment: Manifest updated. Still not working.

Comment: if it is a Xamarin.Android application manifest is regenerated at complile time remove annotations from all activities [Activity(MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true)] and put it only on splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**: There was more than one problem in your question. I addressed two of them but the last one was the icon name.

Android resources can't have the '-' character in the name.
so this is the correction:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/stmicon3"></application>
```

---

### **Initial answer:**

Its wrong to have two activities with the same intent filter for launching.

So, first on your `Manifest`, **remove entirely** the two Activities tags.

For helping debugging this. please change your manifest to this (yes we are ignoring the `Provider` too)

So your final Manifest would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.yournamespace.courier">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="yournamespace"> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

After this, were gonna set the `SplashActivity` as `MainLauncher`:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

And finally the MainActivity:

```
 [Activity(Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: I have done this on the splash screen since that is the main screen to be shown

Comment: I've updated the manifest in the original question and tried the same. Its still not working. I am getting the same error. How does load happen? I am not hitting any breakpoints in the app not even in the `App : Application` class. Need to find out at what point the thing breaks.

Comment: unless there is another better way to share the code?

Comment: github, etc. But dropbox would be fine. btw clean the old comments from here please.

Comment: The issue was with the name of my icon file. I had a `-` sign which created this issue. I changed all the icon names to be alphanumeric only and restarted visual studio. That fixed that problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping with things so far. Appreciate it.

Comment: What solved my original question was what I added in my comment here above which was removing the special characters in the icon name. Your answer here is certainly helpful, but I think not directly related to the solution and might confuse future users in a similar problem. Should I still mark it as accepted? Let me know.

Comment: I've edited my answer now. It reflects the whole problem. guess now its ok to close it and mark it as correct. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You Can Do As Jon Sugguested Or Just Go Into Your Android Device Settings & Application Manager And uninstall the previous version of the application on your android device

Comment: I have uninstalled using both the command and the android device settings and still no effect